# Pandoc Lua how to create an id from a string?

Tags: lua, pandoc

I need to mimic pandoc's way of turning a header's text into an acceptable id string in a Lua filter: remove special characters, turn spaces into dashes.

Is there a command to sanitize a string that way?

Ex: `Les élèves d'hier` becomes: `les-eleves-dhier`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such function built-in, but you can hack one by round-tripping a heading through one of the formats that pandoc supports. This will force the creation of a label that you can use:

```lua
local function make_id (inlines, via)
  local via = via or 'html'
  local heading = pandoc.Header(1, inlines)
  local temp_doc = pandoc.Pandoc{heading}
  local roundtripped_doc = pandoc.read(pandoc.write(temp_doc, via), via)
  return roundtripped_doc.blocks[1].identifier
end
```

Example:

```lua
print(make_id(pandoc.Inlines "Les élèves d'hier"))
```

Will print `les-élèves-dhier`. I believe the output should be the same for all roundtripable formats, but may it isn't.

Comment: thank you very much. I removed the "local" in front of the function and it worked like a charm. I would never have found that. Thank you.

Comment: From my testing, this requires pandoc > 2.17, otherwise it give the error `attempt to call a nil value (field 'Inlines')`. Is there a way to do this for pandoc > 2.11.4?

Comment: @ZNK it might be enough to remove `pandoc.Inlines`, although I didn't test.

Comment: @tarleb, alas no, It's erroring because pandoc.write was only added in 2.17, which is why it's giving the error `attempt to call a nil value (field 'write')`. I guess this is only possible in 2.17 and later